# SQLDatasource parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

How can i set sql parameters for an sqlDatasource in the code behind?
I am trying like this:

```
int id=1;
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM categ WHERE id=@id";
SqlDataSourceArticole.SelectParameters.Add("@id", id);
// and also like this:
SqlDataSourceArticole.SelectParameters.Add("id", id);
```

but it doesn't work? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you add the select parameters before trying to set their default value.

i.e.

```
SqlDataSourceArticole.SelectParameters.Add("@id", id);
SqlDataSourceArticole.SelectParameters["id"].DefaultValue = id.ToString();
```

Comment: Should be `SqlDataSourceArticole.SelectParameters.Add("id", id);` with no `@`

Answer (score 2):

You can update the value by:

```
SqlDataSourceArticole.SelectParameters["id"].DefaultValue = id.ToString();
```

Using the default value can work in this case.

HTH.

Comment: i get 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: The ID parameter has to exist in markup; if you are programmably create the collection of parameters, then when you create the parameter, also set the default value.